# Invalid Control Character in JSON decode (using Python)

Tags: python, json

```
def list(type, extra=""):
if extra != "":
    entity = "http://api.crunchbase.com/v/1/" + type + "/" + extra + ".js?api_key=" + key
    data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(entity))
else: 
    entity = "http://api.crunchbase.com/v/1/" + type + ".js?api_key=" + key
    data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(entity))
return data
```

The function list is called specifically here:

```
x = colink
details = list(co, x)
```

specifically on the instance where x is "if_this_then_that" and co is "company"

The code breaks down on this line when I query on the second line (the entity link is properly formatted). The Error Message is below and the line in the JSON file where the error occurs follows. I am not sure how to handle the unicode error when getting data through a JSON API. Any suggestions on how to remedy this would be appreciated.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "crunch_API.py", line 95, in <module>
  details = list(co, x)
File "crunch_API.py", line 34, in list
  data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(entity))
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 278, in load
  **kw)
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 326, in loads
  return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
  obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
  obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Invalid control character at: line 24 column 89 (char 881)
```

"overview": "\u003Cp\u003EIFTTT is a service that lets you create powerful connections           with one simple statement: if this then that.\u003C/p\u003E", #### Where the error occurs

Comment: Can you edit your post with the contents of `http://api.crunchbase.com/v/1/{type}.js?api_key={key}` and paste more of your `crunch_API.py` file?

Comment: Still trying to figure out how to handle formatting on here. But yes, you can edit the post of the contents using the function list I added above. The link works completely fine, but it seems to not be able to load the  data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(entity))